# How to add a pyspark rolling window based on restricted duplicate values

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:
[image]

Reproduce:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 3), (2, 4, 2), (3, 4, 5), (1, 5, 3), (2, 5, 2), (3, 6, 5)], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I want to restrict the duplicates of column 'b' to two, only two duplicates will be kept, rest will be dropped.
After that, I want to add a new column as 'd', where there will be a rolling window of numeric values in Ascending order as 1,2 like:

[image]

Is there anything like pandas rolling window equivalent in Pyspark which I have failed to dig out from Stack Overflow and documentation where I can do something like what I may have done on pandas:

```
y1 = y[df.COL3 == 'b']
y1 = y1.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.max(x) if len(x)>0 else 0).fillna('drop')y = y1.reindex(y.index, fill_value = 0).loc[lambda x : x!='drop']
```

I am new to PySpark, thanks in advance.

Comment: that's just a[`row_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number). you filter on your row number < 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Window, partition by column b, do row_numner on that window and filter the row numbers less or equal 2:

```
# Prepare data:
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 3), (2, 4, 2), (3, 4, 5), (1, 5, 3), (2, 5, 2), (3, 6, 5)], ['a', 'b', 'c'])

# Actual work
w = Window.partitionBy(col("b")).orderBy(col("b"))
df.withColumn("d", row_number().over(w)).filter(col("d") <= 2).show()

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  4|  3|  1|
|  2|  4|  2|  2|
|  1|  5|  3|  1|
|  2|  5|  2|  2|
|  3|  6|  5|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: That certainly did the job. Interesting how Pyspark works with row_number. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Strayhorn your welcome, I recommend you to check how windows works in spark, it's not very difficult usually it contains partitionBy to create a partition per group of data having the same key then a orderBy to sort data inside each partition, then you can perform some action on each partition like row_number, sum, min, max ...